# How can I edit adjacent selector to a nested one

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have custom radio buttons which I've borrowed from this website: http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/custom-form-radio-checkbox/

Unfortunately, I'm using a helpful plugin which I cannot easily modify which populates my DOM with a nested input inside the label such that...

```
<label>
  <input class="regular-radio">
```

I would like to use the selector `.regular-radio + label` to select the label. However, it only works with:

```
<input class="regular-radio">
<label>
```

I've demonstrated my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BR3MB/

How might I modify that CSS to work off the parent label rather than an adjacent one?
I'd be really troubled to edit the DOM in this case, since there is much relying on that structure already.

Comment: Do you want to select the parent or the child? The question seems unclear. You should give a clear example of the DOM structure and which element you're trying to select in that structure.

Comment: Anurag, there was/is a clear example of the DOM above, see the JS Fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this can't currently be done using CSS as CSS reads from right to left only. This means that the rightmost element in the selector will be the one receiving the styles, and the rightmost element must always be a child or a sibling of any element to the left of it in a selector. The issue with that for you, is the element you want to style is the parent.

There is a parent selector in the works ( http://www.red-team-design.com/css-parent-selector ), but until then you will have to resort to using JavaScript.

With that being said, I think the best solution in this case would be to alter the output of the plugin to something more useful (if at all possible).

Comment: I ended treading down the road of re-factoring the plugin, thanks.

Comment: That the subject of the selector is represented by the rightmost element has *nothing* to do with reading selectors from right to left. Even if you read a selector from left to right, you would still end up with the rightmost compound selector being the subject. For example, `.regular-radio + label` can either mean "Select any `label` that directly follows an element with class `regular-radio`", or "Check each element with class `regular-radio` and select the `label` that directly follows it". In both cases you're trying to match and apply styles to `label`, not `.regular-radio`.

Comment: The subject selector in Selectors 4 isn't technically a parent selector; all it does is change which compound selector represents the subject of a selector. The term "subject" is actually pretty well-defined in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject), even going back to [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#subject) and [Selectors 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#subjects-of-the-selector). RTL matching, on the other hand, is merely an implementation detail that doesn't have any bearing on the spec.

Comment: Perhaps my wording confused you, but the only reason I mention right to left is to then explain that the left hand part of the selector must be a sibling or parent of the right, it can't be a child.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a CSS selector for parent styling sadly.  The only way to get the parent's style would be through Javascript.  On CSS Tricks, [Chris Coyier talks about the upsides and downsides](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/) of the debate to have or not have this selector added to the spec.  Personally, I wish it existed, but wishing never got my code to work.

Comment: Syntactically, a combinator makes much more sense than a pseudo-class. In jQuery, where `:parent` means `:not(:empty)`, it actually makes more sense, because you're saying "select this if is a parent of something", rather than "select this element's parent". One could use a pseudo-element instead like `::parent`, but the parent element is an actual element, not a pseudo-element, so that doesn't make sense either.

Comment: Definitely agree with you.  I was referring to CSS where there specifically is no way to select a parent, but in jQuery, there could be a number of ways I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in CSS to select the parent of an element. You might have to use something like this to select it:

```
label:nth-of-type(x) {}
```

Where x is the number of the label in the parent.